# How do you send a python list via google-cloud-endpoints?

Tags: rpc, google-cloud-endpoints

I would like to retrieve a Python list via Google RPC Protocol / Google Cloud Endpoints.

I have looked into several different message types, but it seems that lists are currently not supported:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/messages/fieldclasses

Is there a work-around, eg. serializing?

Answer (score 0):

You would use a MessageField [1] with a repeated property, eg:

```
class ListItem(messages.Message):
  name = messages.StringField(1)
  number = messages.IntegerField(2)

class List(messages.Message):
  items = messages.MessageField(ListItem, 1, repeated=True)
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/messages/messagefieldclass

Comment: i would like to somehow pass a Python list inside the HTTP request/RPC protocol. Would that work?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how lists are serialized using ProtoRPC messages. Messages are serialized (usually as a JSON object) in the HTTP request body. Unless you are asking a different question?